# Custom Confirm Modal in React using Context

Tags: reactjs, react-context

How can I implement native javascript style confirm modal using context api?

I made a `codesandbox`.

https://codesandbox.io/s/little-sunset-806rdh?file=/src/App.js

Or please see below code.

**context.js**

```
const confirmContext = createContext()

function ConfirmProvider({children}){
    
   const [visible, setVisible] = useState(false)
   const [message, setMessage] = useState('')
   
   const open = (message) => {
     setVisible(true)
     setMessage(message)
   }
   const handleSubmitClick = () => { }
   const handleCancelClick = () => { }

   if (!visible) return <div />
    
   return (
      <ConfirmContext.Provider value={{ open }}>
      <div>
         {message}
         <button onClick={handleSubmitClick}>OK</button>
         <button onClick={handleCancelClick}>Cancel</button>
      </div>
      {children}
      </ConfirmContext.Provider>
   )

}

const useConfirm = () => useContext(ConfirmContext)

export { ConfirmProvider }
```

**delete.js**

```
function Delete(){

    const confirm = useConfirm()
    const handleClick = () => {
       confirm.open('Are you really delete it?')

       // How do I code here when 'OK' or 'Cancel' Button Click?
       // if(confirm.open()){ 
       //      // do something
       // } else {
       //      // do nothing
       // }


    }

    return (
       <div>
          <button onClick={handleClick}>Delete</button>
       </div>
     )

}
```

Answer (score 0):

return `Promise` in `open` function will implement this pattern.

```
  const open = ({ message, confirmText, cancelText }) => {
    setVisible(true)
    setMessage(message)

    return new Promise((res, rej) => {
      resolveCallback = res
    })
  }

  const onConfirmClick = () => {
    window.alert('on confirm click')
    resolveCallback(true)
    setVisible(false)
  }

  const onCancelClick = () => {
    window.alert('on cancel click')
    resolveCallback(false)
    setVisible(false)
  }
```

// use

```
const c = confirm.open('you really delete it?')
if(c) // do something
```